# How to change cell's border whenever new cell is selected in jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, listselectionlistener

I want to change border of cell whenever it is selected regardless by mouse or by keyboard.
It is hard to find smth on net. I tried to use ListSelectionListener but this doesn't work.

If you know some good way to change cell's border, please, reply. 
I welcome any ideas.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a customized TableCellRenderer to do something different when the cell is selected.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer

Looking at the code from the above example you can see how you would need to look at the `isSelected` boolean parameter.

```
 public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
                        JTable table, Object color,
                        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                        int row, int column) {
    Color newColor = (Color)color;
    setBackground(newColor);
    if (isBordered) {
        if (isSelected) {
            ...
            //selectedBorder is a solid border in the color
            //table.getSelectionBackground().
            setBorder(selectedBorder);
        } else {
            ...
            //unselectedBorder is a solid border in the color
            //table.getBackground().
            setBorder(unselectedBorder);
        }
    }
```

However, in your implementation just extend `DefaultTableCellRenderer` and call super() version of `getTableCellRendererComponent` first and just change the cell color.

Comment: Thanks @jzd. I read that tutorial but when time came to use it I went  here probably by habit. You always refer to oracle tutorials!

Answer (score 3):

This is the default behaviour. The cell border is set based on the `Table.focusCellHighlightBorder` property of the table. So you can change the default Border by using the UIManager. See [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) for more information.

If for some reason this doesn't meet your requirements then I would check out [Table Row Renderering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) which will allow you do this in one place instead of creating a custom renderer for every data type in your table.

Comment: In that demo you didn't say how to fetch if cell is selected but you use isRowSelected to know if row is selected. Please, tell how cell should be identified as selected

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi, `you didn't say how to fetch if cell is selected but you use isRowSelected` - You've got to be joking. I showed you a concept that you are free to customize. Did you even think to look at the JTable API for a method that tells you if a cell is selected? `Don't expect people to spoon feed you the code.`

Comment: Yes, how couldn't I get it before?

Comment: I found solution. To get currently selected cell it is not possible to use isCellSelected because it returns true for all cells in selected row. One must know hasFocus property which is determined in JTable.prepareRenderer method. I just copied that method to acccess hasFocus value.